# Type narrowing not working when assigning to local variable within a loop

Tags: typescript

I'm not too sure what's going on and whether this is expected or not. Consider the following code block:

```js
function test()
{
    let test1: number | undefined = 42;

    if (test1 === undefined)
    {
        return;
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        // test1: Object is possibly 'undefined'. ts(2532)
        // 'test2' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.ts(7022)
        const test2 = test1 + 1; 

        // If I remove this line everything is fine
        test1 = test2;
    }
}
```

When the assignment line `test1 = test2` isn't present, Typescript correctly narrows the type of test1 to be a `number` and knows that `test2` is therefore also a `number`. However, adding that line triggers the errors shown above. I'm in strict mode.

If I force the type of test2 it works no problem `const test2: number = test1 + 1`.

Can somebody explain why Typescript is acting this way? When reading the code I do not see what could happen to make Typescript think that `test1` could be anything else than a `number`.

I did find a similar report that may be linked to a Typescript limitation that snowballs into this problem. https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43047